# How to reuse Nginx directives in common

Tags: nginx

I have three locations with some configuration directives in common, so rather than repeat the directives, I'd prefer to inherit the common (proxy cache settings and some `add_header` directives) and only write the difference (`proxy_pass`, in my case):

```
server {
    server_name   mypage.com;
    listen        443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen        [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    root          /opt/myApps/mypage/;
    index         index.jsp;
    charset       utf-8;

    location /data/a/ {
        proxy_cache             azure_cache;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host accountname.blob.core.windows.net;
        proxy_hide_header       "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_ignore_headers    "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_cache_revalidate  on;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;
        proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_lock        on;
        proxy_cache_valid       200 304 30d;
        proxy_cache_valid       404 10m;
        add_header              Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
        add_header              X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_pass              https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/a/;
    }

    location /data/b/ {
        proxy_cache             azure_cache;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host accountname.blob.core.windows.net;
        proxy_hide_header       "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_ignore_headers    "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_cache_revalidate  on;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;
        proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_lock        on;
        proxy_cache_valid       200 304 30d;
        proxy_cache_valid       404 10m;
        add_header              Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
        add_header              X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_pass              https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/b/;
    }

    location /data/c/ {
        proxy_cache             azure_cache;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host accountname.blob.core.windows.net;
        proxy_hide_header       "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_ignore_headers    "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_cache_revalidate  on;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;
        proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_lock        on;
        proxy_cache_valid       200 304 30d;
        proxy_cache_valid       404 10m;
        add_header              Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
        add_header              X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_pass              https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/c/;
    }

    location / {
        # Other stuff here...
    }
}
```

Note the difference in the `proxy_pass` directive.

Is there any way to do that clearer?

PS: edited with real example

Comment: It depends on the directive. Each directive has a context. If that context includes `server`, you can specify it in the `server` block and its value will be inherited by each `location` unless overridden. Otherwise, place all of the common code into a file and use `include` to read the file into each `location`. And the example is bad, as it could be achieved using a single `location`.

Comment: The directives would be proxy cache settings and some add_header directives. How could you do that?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/ The official example already covers that with `proxy.conf`.

Comment: All [`proxy_cache` type directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache) except `proxy_cache_path` can be placed in the `server` context. Multiple [`add_header` directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) are also inherited from the `server` context, but only if there are no `add_header` statements defined within the `location`. If you edit your question and provide a real example, we can provide a real solution.

Comment: @RichardSmith I've added my real example. Hope it will he helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move all of the common statements from the `location` context into the `server` context. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache) for details.

You have an identical set of `add_header` statements in your `location` blocks, so these too can be moved into the `server` context. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) for details.

Technically, the `proxy_set_header Host accountname.blob.core.windows.net;` statement is redundant as the default value is taken from the `proxy_pass` value which is identical.

For example:

```
proxy_cache             azure_cache;
proxy_http_version      1.1;
proxy_set_header        Host accountname.blob.core.windows.net;
proxy_hide_header       "Set-Cookie";
proxy_ignore_headers    "Set-Cookie";
proxy_cache_revalidate  on;
proxy_intercept_errors  on;
proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
proxy_cache_lock        on;
proxy_cache_valid       200 304 30d;
proxy_cache_valid       404 10m;

add_header              Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
add_header              X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

location /data/a/ {
    proxy_pass https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/a/;
}

location /data/b/ {
    proxy_pass https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/b/;
}

location /data/c/ {
    proxy_pass https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/c/;
}
```

---

However, there is a further simplification as the end of the `location` values match the end of the `proxy_pass` values in all three cases and are otherwise identical. So, you can trim these back to achieve the identical result by reducing the three locations into a single block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

For example:

```
location /data/ {
    proxy_pass https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Excellent answer. The last question: simplification only affects readability, isn't it? Performance is the same in both configs, I suppose.

Comment: Probably an insignificant (if any) performance improvement by reducing the number of prefix locations. However, removing redundant code improves maintainability. For example, if in the future `accountname.blob.core.windows.net` needed to be changed - you have four places to edit, instead of one.

Comment: Thanks again. I appreciate it. Cheers!